# yii2 blocking api call and giving failed to open stream: Connection timed

Tags: api, yii2, php-7

I need to call a private api in my app. the call works fine using php script.php.

However, when i copy the same php code into an action of a yii controller it gives me an error

`failed to open stream: Connection timed`

i tried removing the behaviors and other configurations to have a basic yii environment

anyone has an idea why this is happening?

here is some code

```
public function actionInfo() {

        $url = "private url";
        $data = array();
        $data['function'] = "Getinfo";
        $data['login'] = "login";
        $data['password'] = "password";
        $data['input'] = "data";
        $post = http_build_query($data);

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                'method' => "POST",
                'content' => $post,
            ),
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $resultat = "";

        if (!$resultat = file_get_contents($url, false, $context)) {
            $resultat = "Echec de l'envoi de la requête";
        }

        $resultat = json_decode($resultat);

        print_r($resultat);
        echo "\r\n";
```

this code works fine outside yii but in this action it does not!!!!

Comment: Share some code...

Answer (score 0):

it was a server configuration the firewall was blocking my id on the api side